# MySQL: SELECT для LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть 2 таблицы, таблица с `Contracts`, связана 1 ко многим с таблицей `Firms`.

Contracts:

```
+----+--------+---------+
| id | firm_1 |  firm_2 |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 |   1    |    2    |
|  1 |   3    |    2    |
|  1 |   1    |    1    |
+----+--------+---------+
```

Firms:

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 |  ООО |
|  2 |  ИП  |
|  3 |  ОАО |
+----+------+
```

Необходимо при выводе таблице `Contracts` вывести за место `id` названия фирмы. Пример вывода:

```
+----+--------+---------+
| id | firm_1 |  firm_2 |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 |   ООО  |   ИП    |
|  1 |   ОАО  |   ИП    |
|  1 |   ООО  |   ООО   |
+----+--------+---------+
```

На данный момент запрос выглядит так и работа только для 1 поля:

```
SELECT id , Firms.name, firm_2
FROM Contracts
LEFT JOIN Firms ON Firms.id = Contracts.firm_1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Присоедините таблицу `Firms` ещё раз, чтобы использовать её для второго поля. Чтобы отличать таблицы `Firms` (если их несколько раз соединяют), необходимо использовать [алиасы (псевдонимы)](http://dimonchik.com/sql-alias.html), которые позволят различать таблицы.

```
SELECT c.id, f1.name, f2.name 
FROM Contracts с
LEFT JOIN Firms f1 ON f1.id = Contracts.firm_1
LEFT JOIN Firms f2 ON f2.id = Contracts.firm_2
```

Answer (score 6):

Необходимо приджойнить таблицу второй раз. Есть одна не самая очевидная вещь - в этом случае обязательно нужно использовать алиасы для таблиц.

```
SELECT Contracts.id , f1.name, f2.name 
  FROM Contracts
LEFT JOIN Firms as f1 ON f1.id = Contracts.firm_1
LEFT JOIN Firms as f2 ON f2.id = Contracts.firm_2;
```

Если для каждого `Contracts` запись в `Firms` обязана быть, то повесьте `foreign key` для проверки этого факта и используйте `INNER JOIN` вместо `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: А в чем разница для данного примера в INNER JOIN и LEFT JOIN?

Comment: @Skar404 для данного примера ни в чём - результат будет одинаков.

Comment: @Мелкий тут нужен псевдоним для `id` в строке `SELECT`, потому что он есть также в таблице `Firms`

Comment: @Denis, да, действительно. Спасибо, поправил. Skar404, если для всех Contracts будет запись в Firms - то в том и вопрос, что никак не будет отличаться. И зачем тогда left делать?

Comment: @Мелкий вообще для всех записей есть запись в `Firms`, но в любом случаи выборка всех записей которые есть в `Contracts` и если что выводить `Null`, а просто не выводить строку, либо я не понимаю отличия `INNER JOIN` и `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Если записи должны быть всегда - это должен гарантировать foreign key. А не костыли на приложении.